# Change colour of boxes surrounding links in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, color

How can I achieve in the following MWE that the box surrounding the link gets coloured in blue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{a}
    x
  \end{equation}
  \ref{a}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set the specific border colour. In your case, `linkbordercolor={0 0 1}` where the default is `linkbordercolor={1 0 0}` (or red in the RGB model).:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}% http://ctan.org/pkg/color
\usepackage[linkbordercolor={0 0 1}]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{a}
    x
  \end{equation}
  \ref{a}
\end{document}​
```

Alternatively, loading [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) provides the regular "named" colours, allowing one to use

```
\usepackage[linkbordercolor=blue]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
```

Different colours can be used for different hyperlinks. [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides

- `citebordercolor` (RGB colour) with default `{0 1 0}`: The colour of the box around citations
- `filebordercolor` (RGB colour) with default `{0 .5 .5}`: The colour of the box around links to files
- `linkbordercolor` (RGB colour) with default `{1 0 0}`: The colour of the box around normal links
- `menubordercolor` (RGB colour) with default `{1 0 0}`: The colour of the box around Acrobat menu links
- `urlbordercolor` (RGB colour) with default `{0 1 1}`: The colour of the box around links to URLs
- `runbordercolor` (RGB colour) with default `{0 .7 .7}`: Colour of border around ‘run’ links
- `allbordercolors` (RGB colour): Set all border color options

See the [`hyperref` documentation](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-100003.6) (specifically, section **3.6 PDF-specific display options**).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I tried too but I didn't add blanks between the RGB code and hence got an error. By the way, is it also possible to have the box filled?

Comment: @lpdbw: This would most likely have to be set in the PDF specification, to which `hyperref` does not provide an interface, AFAIK. For example, there are many border-specific changes one can implement, as suggested in section **8.12 Entries in a border style dictionary** (p 495) of the [PDF Reference 3rd Ed](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf). Don't know whether PDF specification provides a fill or not. Heiko Oberdiek might be able to elaborate on that.

Comment: If package `xcolor` is loaded, the normal color specifications can be used for the `*bordercolor`s: `linkbordercolor=blue` (since `hyperref` 2007-04-09 6.76a).