# changing box color in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, links

I wish to change the color of boxed links to red. But the code below still produces cyan links. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=false,
  linkbordercolor=red
}
\begin{document}
\href{http://www.tex.stackexchange.com}{Stack exchange link}
\end{document}
```

Comment: covers the same territory: [Change colour of boxes surrounding links in hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67446/579)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `linkbordercolor` option is used for internal links, e.g. for the TOC, equation numbers etc.

For a 'true' hyperlink to a web site use the `urlbordercolor` option, either
with

- `urlbordercolor=red` combined with a colour name
- `urlbordercolor=[1 0 0]` with some RGB colour specification (values from 0 to 1 allowed)

If **all** link borders should appear in red colour use the option `allborders=red` instead

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=false,
%  urlbordercolor=1 0 0  %  possible also
  urlbordercolor=red
}
\begin{document}
\href{http://www.tex.stackexchange.com}{Stack exchange link}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just in case the OP's objective is to make the color of *all* hyperlink boxes red (and not just those of URL links), you may want to mention the option `allcolors`. E.g., setting `allcolors=red` will make all hyperlink box markers red.

Comment: @Mico: I know of that option, but I restricted to the url boxes so far.