# Box around reference and citation

Tags: color, links, border

I want to add a border around my internal references and citation. I have tried what is suggested in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67446/change-colour-of-boxes-surrounding-links-in-hyperref).

Here is my header

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
            \hypersetup{backref=true,       
                    pagebackref=true,               
                    hyperindex=true,                
                    colorlinks=true,                
                    breaklinks=true,                
                    urlcolor= black,                
                    linkcolor= blue,                
                    bookmarks=true,                 
                    bookmarksopen=false,
                    citecolor=black,
                    linkcolor=black,
                    filecolor=black,
                    citecolor=blue,
                    linkbordercolor=blue
}

\title{test}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{align}\label{eq:1}
\ln(ab)=\ln(a) + \ln(b)
\end{align}


my equation is \ref{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

While the citation colour did change to blue, there is no blue border around equation and figure references.

Do I have to set a parameter to TRUE like `colorlinks` to enable the link border to be visible.

Comment: `hyperref` explicitly checks at `\begin{document}` whether `colorlinks` is set to true, and if so, set `pdfborder` to `{0 0 0}`. Maybe one way to go around this is to pass `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}}` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hyperref` package explicitly checks at `\begin{document}` whether `colorlinks` is set to true, and if so, set `pdfborder` to `{0 0 0}` (which means no border).

One way to go around this is to pass `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}}` so that this behaviour is negated, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{backref=true,       
    pagebackref=true,               
    hyperindex=true,                
    colorlinks=true,                
    breaklinks=true,                
    urlcolor= black,                
    linkcolor= blue,                
    bookmarks=true,                 
    bookmarksopen=false,
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkbordercolor=blue
}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}}% <-----------

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
    \ln(ab)=\ln(a) + \ln(b)
    \end{equation}


    my equation is \ref{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are defined `linkcolor` two times, first one is `blue` and the second time redefined as `black`, so as `LaTeX`, most recent defined term will execute, so it the link color turned to black, please remove it and check...

```
            \hypersetup{backref=true,       
                    pagebackref=true,               
                    hyperindex=true,                
                    colorlinks=true,                
                    breaklinks=true,                
                    urlcolor= black,                
                    linkcolor= blue,                
                    bookmarks=true,                 
                    bookmarksopen=false,
%                    citecolor=black,
%                    linkcolor=black,
                    filecolor=black,
                    citecolor=blue,
                    linkbordercolor=blue
}
```

Comment: This doesnt answer the question (completely), which is about getting  a blue link with a blue border around it.

Comment: I do agree with you that the link colour was defined two times. If I apply the correction you proposed, the reference becomes blue, but what I want instead is to have a blue border around the reference as in the post's image I mentioned before