# How do I get boxes around my links?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color, box

I'm trying to add boxes around my links like in [Box around reference and citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383534/box-around-reference-and-citation)  but I don't get the boxes only the number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{theorem}
\usepackage{comment}






 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subcaption}

 \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\roman{subfigure}}

 \usepackage[ruled,vlined,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{backref=true,       
    pagebackref=true,               
    hyperindex=true,                
    colorlinks=false,                
    breaklinks=true,                
    urlcolor= black,                
    linkcolor= blue,                
    bookmarks=true,                 
    bookmarksopen=false,
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkbordercolor={1 0 0}
}
 \AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}}% <-----------
 
\begin{document}




\begin{theorem}\label{lemma1}
adfsdfadf
\end{theorem}

\ref{lemma1}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove `colorlinks=false`?

Comment: @Werner still no box

Comment: This could be due on your pdf viewer, which is what adds the boxes. Try Acrobat ot a browser. See [no border around hyperlinks with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210640/4301).  What are you using to view the pdf?  I can confirm that the given code with TeXShop does indeed display a box.

Comment: @PeterGrill  I was using overleaf. Turns out if I use adobe the red boxes appear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no border around hyperlinks with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210640/no-border-around-hyperlinks-with-hyperref). Voting to close since seems to be the same issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill you can close I'm not sure why overleaf pdf viewer is weird borders appear if I use adobe.