# Make hyperref links only show up if they're external links?

Tags: hyperref, color, links, border

I am trying to make a document, but I do not need hyperref to label links that are internal (since the document is only a few pages long). I would, however, like for links to show up that point **outside** of the document, e.g. urls and external files. I do not want equations, page number references, footnotes, etc. showing up.

I am referring specifically to the colored borders that appear around links (but don't print).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    Here's some test text with a footnote\footnote{Some text, but the footnote shouldn't show up as a link.}.

    \url{http://www.google.com} %this should show up as a link.

    \href{http://www.google.com}{Go to Google} %this should also show up as a link.
\end{document}
```

I can't set `hidelinks` in the options and then set `urlbordercolor` it seems, and I have no idea how to set a border color to be transparent (or else I could try setting each border color type to transparent). <strike>I also don't know what color that blue is for the `urlbordercolor` by default, and I really like it, so I'd rather not change it if possible.</strike> I did find from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67446/change-colour-of-boxes-surrounding-links-in-hyperref) that the `urlbordercolor` is `{0 1 1}` by default; I just typed it in wrong originally, so I thought I had it wrong.

I can't change the link borders to all white because it causes some clipping issues:
[image]

So I think if I wanted to change that, the links would need to be made transparent.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "I do not want equations, page number references, footnotes, etc. showing up." refer to exactly? Does this sentence refer to the colored boxes, hyperref adds around links?

Comment: Please also make your code compilable. Currently it results in quite a number of error messages. Probably you wanted to use `\hyperlink{www.google.com}{Go to Google}` instead of `\hyperref{www.google.com}{Go to Google}`?

Comment: @leandriis Fixed. Typed `\hyperref` instead of `\href`. Sorry about that. I am not sure what the difference is between `\href` and `\hyperlink`?

Comment: no \hyperlink is wrong too, you probably mean \href, and you should add the protocol: https://www ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do have the `www`, should I add the `https://` part as well?

Comment: yes, www alone is not a complete url and will only work if the pdf viewer helps.

Comment: Probably `\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}` results in the desired output?

Comment: @leandriis it's close, but it removes the border from the urls and changes their color away from the default? If I remove `colorlinks` I get the borders back, but unfortunately all of the others come back too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fixed the post to include `http://` on the links. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: `\hypersetup{citebordercolor={1 1 1},linkbordercolor={1 1 1}}`  changes the border color to white while keeping the light blue border color of url links.

Comment: @leandriis Updated the post. It causes some sort of typesetting/clipping issue, probably because the border is writing over the text. I think if anything it'd have to be transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `hyperref` bundle there is an additional package called `nohyperref` that defines all commands of `hyperref` but makes them do nothing. This package is intended to disable hyperlinks completely without causing errors if documents use any of the commands defined by `hyperref` (for example `\hyperref` or `\phantomsection` or any of the bookmark commands).

After loading `hyperref` normally, you can use some of the code from this package to selectively disable only the parts that you don't want, i.e., internal links, and leave the other commands untouched.

Edit: as noted in comments you may want to keep the anchors in the pdf to allow for external linking. This applies to links in the pdf only (for example http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf#subsection.3.8 that directly links to subsection 3.8 of the hyperref pdf manual), whereas 'external' references within LaTeX (such as with `\input` or `\include` or the `xr-hyper` package) are not affected with this code.

MWE for this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
% first six lines of nohyperref.sty
% keep anchors
%\let\hyper@@anchor\@gobble
\def\hyper@link#1#2#3{#3}%
%\let\hyper@anchorstart\@gobble
%\let\hyper@anchorend\@empty
\let\hyper@linkstart\@gobbletwo
\let\hyper@linkend\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\label{mysec}
    Here's some test text with a footnote\footnote{Some text, but the 
    footnote shouldn't show up as a link.} 
    in Section~\ref{mysec} on page~\pageref{mysec}.

    \url{http://www.google.com} %this should show up as a link.

    \href{http://www.google.com}{Go to Google} %this should also show up as a link.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the inserted code may disable too much or too little functionality, check carefully if you observe any unintended effects.

Comment: You probably wish to keep anchors/named destinations/targets so within external resources, e.g., websites or other .pdf-files, you can link to specific sections of the document.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Does this answer prevent linking other documents into this one? I am still able to reference, for example, Equation 4 in my working document, although the link to Equation 4 is no longer active.

Comment: @Publius LaTeX's cross-referencing-mechanism which serves the purpose of obtaining textual phrases denoting sectioning-numbers or equation-numbers and the like is **not** affected. That mechanism is in effect only while the LaTeX-compiler is running and creating the .pdf-file. The hyperref-package adds things which are in effect while the .pdf-file is displayed by a pdf-viewing-program: It turns equation-numbers and  section-headings into named destinations/targets/anchors.And it turns cross-references created via `\ref`/`\pageref` etc into hyperlinks to the named destinations/targets/anchors.

Comment: @Publius So with this answer within the pdf both hyperlinks (which is desired) and named destinations/targets/anchors (which could be also linked from other documents/websites) don't come into being. In the answer six commands are modified. If the three `...@anchor...`-commands are not modified, links will not be created but named destinations/targets/anchors for linking will be created. In any case the names of these named destinations/targets/anchors will not be these of the corresponding referencing-labels. Because hyperref uses its own algorithms for assigning names to ...

Comment: @Publius ...named destinations/targets/anchors. You can fiind out the names of named destinations/targets/anchors by looking at the `\newlabel`-entries in the .aux-file. With linux-machines there is also the `pdfinfo`-program which can be invoked as `pdfinfo -dests <.pdf-file>` for listing the names of all linkable named destinations/targets/anchors within the <.pdf-file>

Comment: @UlrichDiez thanks for the comment, I have edited my answer to address the issue.

Comment: Wow, this stuff is way over my head. I think I understand what you're saying, though. Thanks both so much for the responses!

Answer (score 2):

The following crude hack *seems* to work with

- pdflatex — `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)...LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`
- xelatex — `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)...LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`
- lualatex — `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)...LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`

But I give no warranties as

- I did not really delve into studying the hyperref-driver-files.
- evaluating things like pdfborder and pdfborderstyle is is not just a matter of pdf-version and pdf-specification but is also a matter of how the program used for viewing/displaying the pdf-file in question works:

  [Table 164 — Entries common to all annotation dictionaries of the Portable Document Format (PDF) 1.7 specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf#M11.9.19657.2Heading.742.Annotation.Flags) says that border-specification (the `pdfborder=...`-thingie with hyperref) is of pattern

  ```
  [⟨horizontal corner radius⟩ ⟨vertical corner radius⟩ ⟨border width⟩[⟨length of dashes⟩ ⟨length of gap between dashes⟩]]
  ```

  ; specifications for dashes being optional; everything specified in "default user space units"; [section 8.3.2.3 User Space  of the Portable Document Format (PDF) 1.7 specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf#G7.1849398) says that by default a user space unit is (1/72) inch, i.e., is 1bp (=1 big point) according to what is said in Chapter 10: Dimensions of the TeXbook. (1bp = 1 big point = (1/72) inch; 1pt = 1 printer's point = (1/72.27) inch.)

  If I specify `pdfborder={5 5 1 [3 2]}`, then this means dashed lines; dashes of length 3bp; gap between dashes of length 2bp; thickness of dashes 1bp; round corners of corner radius 5bp both vertical and horizontal.

  When displaying the resulting pdf-file with Chromium Version 76.0.3809.100 (Developer-Build), then no borders at all are shown.

  When displaying the resulting pdf-file with Firefox Quantum 69.0.2, then solid lines with round corners are shown.

  When displaying the resulting pdf-file with Okular 1.3.2 and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Version 2020.012.20043, then dashed lines, no round corners but squared corners are shown.

Be aware that the footnote is still a link, but not surrounded by colored borders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,
            %allbordercolors={},
            %citebordercolor={0 1 0},
            %filebordercolor={0 .5 .5},
            %linkbordercolor={1 0 0},
            %menubordercolor={1 0 0},
            %urlbordercolor={0 1 1},
            %runbordercolor={0 .7 .7},
            %pdfborder={0 0 1},
            %pdfborderstyle={/S/S/W 1}
           ]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\Hy@AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifxetex
    \edef\@innerlinkbordercolor#1]{\@linkbordercolor]/BS<</S/S/W 0>>}%
    \def\@linkbordercolor{\@innerlinkbordercolor}%
  \fi
  \ifluatex\ifpdf
    \edef\@innerlinkbordercolor#1]{\@linkbordercolor]/BS<</S/S/W 0>>}%
    \def\@linkbordercolor{\noexpand\@innerlinkbordercolor}%
  \fi\fi
  \ifPDFTeX\ifpdf
    \edef\@innerlinkbordercolor#1]{\@linkbordercolor]/BS<</S/S/W 0>>}%
    \def\@linkbordercolor{\noexpand\@innerlinkbordercolor}%
  \fi\fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Here's some test text with a footnote\footnote{Some text, but the footnote shouldn't show up as a link.}.

    \url{http://www.google.com} %this should show up as a link.

    \href{http://www.google.com}{Go to Google} %this should also show up as a link.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really involved answer- apologies, but I will have to read it in a little while.